# Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fabric-shim'

Tags: blockchain, ibm-blockchain

I am relatively new to blockchain. Trying to set up the project but getting an error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fabric-shim'.

node_modules/fabric-contract-api/types/index.d.ts:10:51 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fabric-shim'
10 import { ChaincodeStub, ClientIdentity } from 'fabric-shim';

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try running this in the cli

```
npm install --save fabric-shim
```

Comment: Hi, I was running npm install --fabric-shim but in the directory. When I did it globally, it resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekKochar running npm install globally isn't recommended if you provide your directory structure I may be able to help you

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. What i did after installing the fabric shim globally. I made the new project and everything after is working fine.

Comment: why wound't you recommend it?